# create tar.gz file and name it using a variable

Tags: python, linux, tar

I'm trying to create a tar.gz file of an XGBoost model by running a shell command using python. The following code works:

```
ts = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
model_name = "model-" + ts
xgb._Booster.save_model(model_name)
!tar czvf model.tar.gz $model_name
```

However, I want to use `model_name` in the naming of the tar.gz file, but can't figure out how to do that. The following does NOT work:

```
!tar czvf $model_name.tar.gz $model_name
```

How can I do this so that the value stored in `model_name` is the name of the tar.gz file I create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ipython?

If so, I think you should do it like this:

```py
!tar czvf {model_name}.tar.gz {model_name}
```

I didn't test your tar command, but I checked and the following works:

```py
a = "myfile"
!touch {a}.txt
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This works but one caveat I get is that tar doesn't support numeric characters.

Comment: What error do you get? I just tried (on Mac), doing a = "123" and adding a tar command, and it worked.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I had some typos initially. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

It does not know where to end your variable so put it inside a parenthesis.

```
!tar czvf ${model_name}.tar.gz ${model_name}
```